# Openrefine: text facet by counting

Tags: openrefine, clusterize

I've a *huge* file primary composed of book metadata (author, title, date, url). My problem is that I want to operate on author names (which are often repeated: an author can have hundreds of records) and I want to operate on the subset of these authors that have more than X records.

For example, I have 200 records related to "William Shakespeare", but only one 1 record of "John Black", etc. The point is, being this a classic power law, I have hundred thousands authors, the majority of them with 1-2 records.

Using "Text facet" > "count" is impossible, because my computer freezes.

Is there a query to have the text facet of just some records, based on their count?

Comment: Did you try to use custom text facet  ? Like first of all you remove blanks ( Facet > Customized Facets> Facet by Blank) and then customized text facet ( Facet > Customized Text Facet). And if it's a problem of memory, I recommend you cut in half the files and process them in batch.

Comment: Yes, I tried. I already allocated more memory, but I need the entire file, anyway, for other operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a custom text facet with the following GREL expression (replace `COLUMNS_NAME` by your actual column name):

`facetCount(value, "value", "COLUMN_NAME")  > 100`

You can edit the comparison (in the example every count great than 100).

To display only exact count match you need to use two `==` like this:

`facetCount(value, "value", "COLUMN_NAME")  == 100`

More details on this [video + tutorail on facet by facet count](http://kb.refinepro.com/2011/11/facet-by-facet-count.html)